# Terminating a c# Console application

Tags: c#, console, exit, terminate

I am trying to close my c# console application (running without debugging) and nothing is working... i have tried all the usual suspects with different exit codes but nothing is terminating it =/ is it because the option is in a bunch of nested if statements? Its probably something really simple i'm missing but its hurting my brain now someone help please! I've tried :

```
System.Environment.Exit(0);
System.Environment.Exit(1);
System.Environment.Exit(-1);
return;
Application.Exit(); //(wont even except it)
```

if context helps i have used nested if statements to check if the user has inputted a number or the letter 'q' if they have inputted a number a calculation is carried out, if the have entered the letter q then the program is to exit and for anything else error statements are outputted.

```
string userInput;
int userInputDigit = 0;
double userCost = 0;
char userInputChar;

userInput = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

if (int.TryParse(userInput, out userInputDigit))
{
    if (userInputDigit <= 50)
    {
        userCost = (price * userInputDigit);
        Console.WriteLine("You have purchased {0} Widgets at a cost of {1:c0}", userInputDigit, userCost);
    }
    else if ((userInputDigit > 50) && (userInputDigit <= 80))
    {
        userCost = (price * 50) + ((userInputDigit - 50) * (price - 1));
        Console.WriteLine("You have purchased {0} Widgets at a cost of {1:c0}", userInputDigit, userCost);
    }
    else if ((userInputDigit > 80) && (userInputDigit <= 100))
    {
        userCost = (price * 50) + (30 * (price - 1)) + ((userInputDigit - 80) * (price - 2.50));
        Console.WriteLine("You have purchased {0} Widgets at a cost of {1:c0}", userInputDigit, userCost);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error! Please input a number between 0 and 100");
    }

}
else if (char.TryParse(userInput, out userInputChar))
{
    if ((userInput == "q") || (userInput == "Q"))
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Letter Inputted");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error! Please input a number or 'q' to quit");
}
```

Comment: How are you running it?  Are you selecting "Debug-->Start without Debugging" in Visual Studio?  Are you manually opening up a console window and then typing in the .exe name?

Comment: So you've written a console program, and you presumably run it from the command line. It should exit by itself when execution reaches the end of the main function. If you comment out everything inside of main, build your program, and run it, it should run and exit. Does it?

Comment: In the debugger, check whether `System.Environment.Exit(0)` is even executed.

Comment: Would be better to see the code itself, if possible. Otherwise, are you exiting the Main method (by return; from within the Main method)?

Comment: yes i am using start without debugging i would like to bypass the press any key to exit i would like the letter 'q' being pressed (pressing enter to submit it) to exit it... i'm not sure how to check if its been executed

Comment: if i posted the code would you need to see all of if statement or just the part its in? as its too much code for the amount of characters i have =/ i only have one method - The Main one and I would just like to close the window thats running as im running it inside the visual environment i though environment.exit would be the one but it wont work =[

Comment: @HollyMarieBatchelor it's not very clear what problem do you have. `Environment.Exit` terminates console process.

Comment: looks like your condition to exit isn't met, try adding your code for this condition- it might help.

Comment: ive added code ^ im baffled because by theory it should work and its really annoying me!

Comment: @HollyMarieBatchelor and which message do you see on console? Maybe its `Error! Please input a number or 'q'`?

Comment: nope it accepts the if statement as to check it worked i first inputted a console.writeline to check it got to the right exception so i enter the letter q press enter and it just says "press any key to continue" telling the user to end the program which they just did by pressing q (only they didn't =/)

Comment: to send it so the console can "readline"? im not looking for a char its entered as string as the user may enter a two or three digit number too then the if statements figure out what the user has entered and converts it to the type of variable it needs to be... char or int

Comment: Did you read lazyberezovsky's answer or mine?  Your problem is that you are using Visual Studio to start the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop and just let Main return normally. Furthermore, I also tried to simplify the condition checking a bit along with the string comparison and parsing. Your error message suggests a validation range ("between" 0 and 100) that is not actually enforced by the preceding if/else if logic. For instance your first case (... <= 50) would be true if user enters a negative value. Also, I did not see where price was ever declared so I made up a constant in my example.

```cs
static bool ExitRequired(string line)
{
    return string.Equals(line, "q", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const double price = 10;
    int userInputDigit;
    double userCost;
    string line = null;

    while (!ExitRequired(line))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number or press 'q' to exit...");
        line = Console.ReadLine();

        if (ExitRequired(line))
            break;

        if (int.TryParse(line, out userInputDigit) 
            && userInputDigit > 0 
            && userInputDigit < 100)
        {
            if (userInputDigit <= 50)
            {
                userCost = (price * userInputDigit);
                Console.WriteLine("You have purchased {0} Widgets at a cost of {1:c0}", userInputDigit, userCost);
            }
            else if ((userInputDigit > 50) && (userInputDigit <= 80))
            {
                userCost = (price * 50) + ((userInputDigit - 50) * (price - 1));
                Console.WriteLine("You have purchased {0} Widgets at a cost of {1:c0}", userInputDigit, userCost);
            }
            else if ((userInputDigit > 80) && (userInputDigit <= 100))
            {
                userCost = (price * 50) + (30 * (price - 1)) + ((userInputDigit - 80) * (price - 2.50));
                Console.WriteLine("You have purchased {0} Widgets at a cost of {1:c0}", userInputDigit, userCost);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error! Please input a number between 0 and 100");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Ill try it out... Price was declared earlier in program as I used it in a loop to output the price of widgets in increments of 10... I only used a for loop and demonstrating loop is the assignment purpose so it may benefit my understanding! Would this (do while?) loop keep the program asking for an input until the user enters q?

Comment: Correct... If this helps then please mark this as the answer or let me know what I am missing and I'll try to improve it thanks.

Comment: I shall do but won't have a chance till tomorrow after work so shall let you know then =]

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't actually exit the program if the user inputs q... would I add this as another if statement?

Comment: nevermind i moved the final else statement onto the end of the nested ifs and put close program in its place =] thankyou ever so much for that loop!

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need to do is to right-click on your project, choose "Properties"and then (quoting msdn.com):

> To set this linker option in the Visual Studio development environment
>
> Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Setting
>   Visual C++ Project Properties.
>
> Click the Linker folder.
>
> Click the System property page.
>
> Modify the SubSystem property.

For the SubSystem, pick Console. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: will this apply for c# application?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to try the application.close() function. It has saved my day many times. If it doesnt help, let me know.

Comment: i tried that =[ it doesn't like "application" for some reason (it doesn't appear in the drop down)

Answer (score 1):

I would first run your app in debug and check to make sure your Application.Exit is actually getting hit. This may shed some light onto why the app isn't exiting.

You should use Environment.Exit(0). This appears to be a better way to end Console apps.

Source: http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx

If this code is in Main I would recommend using a return; after your call to exit the app.

Comment: yes it ends when debugging but i'm meant to run it in the environment and use code to exit on request i've tried environment.exit(0); but it still says "press any key to continue"

Comment: Is there a Console.ReadLine() before your call to exit the application?

Comment: Or, are you using build time directives like  #if debug#  to do something when debugging?

Comment: nope the readline is before all the if statements... the end of the code above is the absolute end of my program (with a few more curly parenthesis)

Comment: Interesting, I ran your code in a new console app (in visual studio 2010) and it ran and exited the app just fine. I think your logic is probably sound. You may want to check the response from Alicja Puacz above. You may have some quirky project properties that need to be changed for it work in Release mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting console application from Visual Studio not in debug mode (Ctrl+F5), then console window stays open *after* application finished execution. And it prompts `Press any key to continue...`. **Again, at this point your console application has exited.**

When you will run *.exe file, then your console will close without asking for key press. That's just Visual Studio 'feature' - it runs `cmd.exe` telling it to run your executable and then pause.

Here is what Visual Studio does when you start application without debugging (you can copy this to *.bat file and run it)

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
"Path\To\Your\ConsoleApplication.exe"
PAUSE
```

Comment: yeah they were my thoughts but the assignment asks that 'q' is to terminate the program and we haven't been told to debug our programs =/ thanks for everyone's help I shall have to email my tutor and request for her to explain what the assignment is asking =/

Comment: Ahh so just miscommunication in what the task is then I guess... Thanks =]

Answer (score 0):

The "press any key to continue" text is added by when you run the project from Visual Studio.

Instead, go to the bin and run it from there.

Make sure you build the project before you run it.  If you run from VS it will automatically build if needed, but running the file from windows explorer does not do this.